# iOS saving core data to server/cloud

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, synchronization, xml-serialization

I'm using core data in our iOS universal application and want the ability for the user to back their data up to our server. So they can log in with another device and pull down that data to that device. Has anyone got any advice on this? I want to analyse the data at the server to synchronise information with our stores as well, so the data must be readable via the server end as well.

I want to send the entire core data store over in one push, so will be an XML mashup of entities from the core data store that will be deciphered on retrieval.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your scheme looks fine. what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have accomplished this using GDataxml to build the xml string and push it through a web service at the server end. Performance is great.

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicating some iCloud functionality here. Why not leave the cloud storage and retrieval to iCloud and then when the app starts, synchronise with your server

Comment: I need to do a fair bit of stuff with the data pushed to the server. Just didnt include that in the question, thought that it would complicate it.